# How can I refresh ListFragment on onesignal notificationReceived method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onesignal

I'm trying to update ListFragment after notification receive. but I can't update ListFragment. 
How can I do that?

```
class NotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
@Override
public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
    JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
    String customerName;
    String quantity;
    if (data != null) {
        customerName = data.optString("customerName", null);
        quantity = data.optString("quantity", null);
        if (customerName != null)
        {
            //Insert To Database And Update ListFragment
        }
    }
}
}
```

I used this code to update my fragment but it only works when I use it in click event of a button but not in a method.

```
    ListFragment fr =(ListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    fr.onCreate(null);
```

Even I tried to reload fragment or activity or application!

Comment: You can try an event-driven approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update the `ListView` inside a `ListFragment`, you need to call `getListAdapter()` on it, then you cast the `ListAdapter` received to the necessary class and update it. How you do that depends on the kind of the adapter used by the fragment.

Don't ever call `onCreate` yourself, by the way. It's only supposed to be called by the Android framework.